# Is it possible to add infinite scrolling to React Tool Box Table body?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-toolbox

I am using [react-toolbox](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/blob/2.0.0-beta.2/components/table/readme.md) table component in my app(react-toolbox for material styles implementation). I need to add infinite scrolling pagination for the table body. I found some libraries which does this for me, some of those are [react-infinite](https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite), [react-infinite-scroller](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller), But the problem is, to use any library I need to put table rows as children inside the their library component, but ract-toolbox table does not allow me to use any `div`'s or special components inside, from the docs:

> An element that represents a row in the Table. It should be place as a
>   direct descendant of Table and it should has TableCells children. It
>   receives extra properties from Table to decide if checkboxes should be
>   placed as a first column.

Actually there is a closed [issue](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/issues/808) on their library but it does not solved my problem. Please help me to do this, or suggest me a suitable library (or) if there is any other way to infinite pagination with out using any library?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap a table inside a div and give a fixed height to that div also make `overflow-y: scroll`  table will be rendered inside the div which will be scrollable and also of fixed height.

Then render this whole markup as children of `react-infinite-scroller`

Comment: Yeah, after lot of tries, I have done this in similar way as you explained using react-infinite-scroller only. Thanks for the time to answer the question :)

Comment: No probs..pleasure was mine