# How to import react-infinite-scroller library in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I want to import this [react-infinite-scroller](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller) react library in a rails project but meet some problems. After I installed it, I could not import it using `import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';` or `var InfiniteScroll = require('react-infinite-scroller')['default'];` in application.js. There would be a `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal` for the first one and `ReferenceError: require is not defined` for the second one.

I also tried this library [react-infinite](https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite) and installed it using bower. I used like this

```
        <react-infinite containerHeight={200} elementHeight={40}>
      <ContentTable
        data={this.state.tableData}
        filterText={this.state.filterText}
        onUserClick={this.handleUserClick}
        dataType={this.props.dataType}
        showPublic={this.state.publicCheckbox}
      />
        </react-infinite>
```

It was imported I guess because I could see the component in the html.[image]

But there was no infinite scrolling on the table.

I think [react-infinite-scroller](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller) might save me because I saw [Is it possible to add infinite scrolling to React Tool Box Table body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631339/is-it-possible-to-add-infinite-scrolling-to-react-tool-box-table-body/47515518#47515518). But I could not import it right.

This project is 5 years old and I am new to react. Could someone save me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the Webpacker gem for Rails 5.

https://github.com/rails/webpacker

This allows you to write React.js components and include the packs (components/scripts) using `javascript_pack_tag`.

It also allows for ES6 syntax, which is what you are trying to do with your import statement. It allows for the require statement as well, as long as you install that library using npm.

Comment: The project is using Rails 4 :(